# Using yeoman to scaffold a template contained in a git-repo?

Tags: git, npm, yeoman

Is it possible to somehow create a yeoman generator that simply clones a sepcified git-repo(and branch), and the removes the .git?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way..

Basically what I would like to achive is the possibility to from a command-window in Windows or OSX.. to get a few options.. based on the selected option I would like to clone a git repo and checkout a specific branch and then delete the .git to lose the git-connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generator that uses Yeoman's api for fetching GIT repos from remote:

```js
'use strict';

var generators = require('yeoman-generator');


module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function () {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  // (1) Prompting
  prompting: function() {
    var done = this.async();
    this.prompt([{
      type: 'list',
      name: 'repo',
      message: 'Select a Repo',
      choices: [{
        name: 'Yeoman Generator Repo',
        value: 'generator'
      }, {
        name: 'Yeoman Yo Repo',
        value: 'yo'
      }]
    }], function (answers) {
      this.repo = answers.repo;
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },

  // (2) Writing
  writing: function () {
    var done = this.async();
    this.remote('yeoman', this.repo, (err, remote) => {
      remote.bulkDirectory('.', this.repo);
      done();
    });  
  }
});
```

At `(1) Prompting` we use Yeoman's basic API for prompting for user input. See [Interacting with the user](http://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html) for more information.

At `(2) Writing` we use Yeoman's `remote()` API to fetch a repository from Github, which is documented [here](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_remote.html). As you can see in the docs an optional third argument may be the name of a branch.